# Botched my Nginx install, making it worse

Tags: mysql, php, nginx, owncloud-server

having an issue. Trying to do Owncloud install and Nginx is not working. Followed directions, but I missed something is all I can come too. Here is what I have from my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/defualt.conf

```
server {
listen 8080 default_server;
listen [::]:8080 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Here is Nginx status

```
ginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
 Loaded: loaded(/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-09-01 10:25:44 PDT; 1h 31min ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Main PID: 21210 (nginx)
Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
       ├─21210 nginx: master process        /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
       ├─21211 nginx: worker process
       ├─21212 nginx: worker process
       ├─21213 nginx: worker process
       └─21214 nginx: worker process

Sep 01 10:25:44 Kodi-Server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 01 10:25:44 Kodi-Server systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Here is nginx -t

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

UFW is currently disabled to see what else is the issue. What am I missing or what can I provide?

Comment: run `sudo nginx -t` to see where the error(s) might be! I also see `started` so what is the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen updated

Comment: So i rebooted, and now I can see my computers IP, 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 but not my external IP

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit the line:

```
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
```

and write only the exact name of your index page, say  `index.html;`  for instance. This is how I managed with my own Nginx server.

After second thought, the problem might be just to add port number " :8080 " to be able to see the site with external address ( ???.???.???.???:8080 ).

I may have found the problem, it just happened to me. This is possibly linked to ubuntu firewall, it can be stopped with sudo ufw disable. This worked for me.